# How to find the right openssl version

Tags: linux, openssl

We need an old openssl version (0.9.x) for a legacy project.
I found the download page for these versions [on the openssl home page](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/0.9.x/).

However, there are a lot of archives with suffixes like `za`, `a` etc.

What are theses suffixes for and how do I find out which one to use?

**EDIT**: I thought these may be different rc's or so, but it seems like all of them were created within a 30s period.

Comment: Everything on that page is a standard gzip compressed tar file. Where are you getting `.a` and `.za` from?

Comment: There are files like `openssl-0.9.6m.tar.gz` (notice the `m`) or `openssl-0.9.8zd.tar.gz` (has a `zd` suffix)

Comment: ... oh. That's just part of the version number.